# Failed to complete Gradle execution cause: org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.console.ConsoleMetaData

Tags: java, android, android-studio, groovy, gradle

Android studio was working as well, when running the app this error shows up: Failed to complete Gradle execution cause: org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.console.ConsoleMetaData

and there is warning in build.gradle (Module: app): 'android' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'

and here the screen shoots:

[error messages while building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWbm6.png)

[and this while cleaning project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at3P1.png)

i deeply search on the web but no luck.

*Note: this error shows when i open any app i developed already!

Comment: Does it work from the command line? And maybe providing code would be easier to help with than screenshots of code?

Comment: please make sure this is not a linux problem, try to restart you computer

Comment: @tim_yates
i solved the problem and i will post the answer now :)

Comment: @MounirElfassi not a linux problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Delete all empty dependencies{} in the Top-level build.

2- Open File-> Settings-> Build, Execution, Deployment-> Build Tools-> Gradle, and choose from project-level settings section "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended) and click Apply then Ok.

3- Open Build-> Clean project the Rebuild project.

The Gradle will loading again and the error will disappear.

Happy Coding :).